# To calculate the values passed to subcomponents at the desired timing?

Tags: react-native

I created a function that delivers an array to the modal when the button is pressed.

In modal, calculations are made based on the array delivered.

However, because the arrangement is getting bigger, there is a lag between delivering and calculating the arrangement every time the button is pressed.

So **I want to deliver the arrangement every time I press the button, but only proceed with the calculation when I open the modal.**

However, it is difficult to find relevant documents or examples because I am a beginner in react-native.

If you have a friend who knows anything, help me! If you have a good opinion, please give me advice. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Can I see your code please? The modal file and how you pass the data

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. But when I looked it up again, the problem was in modal itself. I solved it by using a different modal. Thank you again!